Python: Multiprocessing took longer than sequential, why?
I have this code, it generates 2,000,000 points uniformly distributed in a bounding box and does some calculations to partition the points based on some criteria.
import numpy as np

from draw import draw
import time

X = 0
Y = 1
N = 2000000

max_x = -100000
max_y = -100000
min_x = 100000
min_y = 100000

points = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, (N, 2))

start = time.time()
max_x_index = np.argmax(points[:, X])
max_y_index = np.argmax(points[:, Y])
min_x_index = np.argmin(points[:, X])
min_y_index = np.argmin(points[:, Y])

p_right = points[max_x_index]
p_top = points[max_y_index]
p_left = points[min_x_index]
p_bottom = points[min_y_index]

top_right = points[
points[:, X] > ((points[:, Y] - p_top[Y]) / (p_right[Y] - p_top[Y])) * (p_right[X] - p_top[X]) + p_top[X]]
top_left = points[
points[:, X] < ((points[:, Y] - p_top[Y]) / (p_left[Y] - p_top[Y])) * (p_left[X] - p_top[X]) + p_top[X]]
bottom_right = points[
points[:, X] > ((points[:, Y] - p_bottom[Y]) / (p_right[Y] - p_bottom[Y])) * (p_right[X] - p_bottom[X]) + p_bottom[
X]]
bottom_left = points[
points[:, X] < ((points[:, Y] - p_bottom[Y]) / (p_left[Y] - p_bottom[Y])) * (p_left[X] - p_bottom[X]) + p_bottom[X]]

end = time.time()
print(end - start)

The output is usually 0.09, which is in seconds. The most time-consuming section is the last four computations to get top_right, top_left, bottom_right, and bottom_left. I rewrite the code as follows
import numpy as np
from draw import draw
import time
import multiprocessing

N = 2000000
X = 0
Y = 1
points = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, (N, 2))

max_x = -100000
max_y = -100000
min_x = 100000
min_y = 100000

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
top_right = manager.list()
top_left = manager.list()
bottom_right = manager.list()
bottom_left = manager.list()


def set_top_right():
    global X, Y, points, p_top, p_right, top_right
    top_right.extend(points[
        points[:, X] > ((points[:, Y] - p_top[Y]) / (p_right[Y] - p_top[Y])) * (p_right[X] - p_top[X]) + p_top[X]])


def set_top_left():
    global X, Y, points, p_top, p_left, top_left
    top_left.extend(points[
        points[:, X] < ((points[:, Y] - p_top[Y]) / (p_left[Y] - p_top[Y])) * (p_left[X] - p_top[X]) + p_top[X]])


def set_bottom_right():
    global X, Y, points, p_bottom, p_right, bottom_right
    bottom_right.extend(points[
        points[:, X] > ((points[:, Y] - p_bottom[Y]) / (p_right[Y] - p_bottom[Y])) * (p_right[X] - p_bottom[X]) +
        p_bottom[X]])


def set_bottom_left():
    global X, Y, points, p_bottom, p_left, bottom_left
    bottom_left.extend(points[
        points[:, X] < ((points[:, Y] - p_bottom[Y]) / (p_left[Y] - p_bottom[Y])) * (p_left[X] - p_bottom[X]) +
        p_bottom[X]])


start = time.time()
max_x_index = np.argmax(points[:, X])
max_y_index = np.argmax(points[:, Y])
min_x_index = np.argmin(points[:, X])
min_y_index = np.argmin(points[:, Y])

p_right = points[max_x_index]
p_top = points[max_y_index]
p_left = points[min_x_index]
p_bottom = points[min_y_index]

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=set_top_right)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=set_top_left)
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=set_bottom_right)
p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=set_bottom_left)

p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()
p4.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()
p4.join()

end = time.time()

print(end - start)

and surprisingly it became worse, about 0.15 seconds. I'm almost new to Python, however, I guess both approaches are a single thread and there are no I.O. operations. My Laptop CPU is core i5 generation 11 and I expected each core to take one of the processes and make it faster. Then why is this slower?

Have you done some profiling? Where is the bottleneck?

@jabaa Yes. p1.start() p2.start() p3.start() p4.start() takes 0.14 seconds.

It could be, that's the overhead of mulitprocessing. Do you have profiling data for set_top_right, set_top_left, set_bottom_right and set_bottom_left? If it's ~0.01-0.02 seconds, it's probably the overhead.

You compare a shared memory list to a numpy ndarray. That has a ton of serialization overhead. Honestly, kudos to the shared memory implementation for only being slightly slower

Then what shall I do? Like I said Im new to python

Why do you want to use multiprocessing for an app that runs 0.09 seconds?

This is the first step of a preprocessing algorithm. Mathematically the algorithm is running in O(n), I need to thave the best implementation. So I try to make every step as best as I can.

as an aside, all your global statements are pointless and don't do anything (imo these should raise an error)

working with numpy is often orders of magnitude faster than working with a list, especially, a manager.List, which requires serialization and deserialization. Note, you are still copying points and all the other state in each subprocess. Using a manager.List is unlikely to beat serial numpy.

@juanpa.arrivillaga Can I share a numpy array among processes? I think doing this will solve the issue

@MamaD yes, potentially, specifically with numpy it is possible. I checked with a library called numexpr, though, which you should consider. See my

numpy already does parallelization, and it does it all inside a single process (avoiding the cost of moving data across process boundaries, which is generally significant). When you have a job that numpy can parallelize, you almost never want to use multiprocessing, which has far more overhead. (multiprocessing isn't a silver hammer -- it only makes things faster in very narrow, specific cases). And using both numpy and multiprocessing together means you get CPU contention slowing you down, as each of them tries to use all of your cores, meaning you end up with more demand than you have CPUs

@CharlesDuffy that depends. But it is definitely something to keep in mind.

@juanpa.arrivillaga, fair nuff, edited to add "almost". :)

(to put it differently: multiprocessing is a tool specifically meant to fix the problem of the global interpreter lock preventing multiple threads from modifying the state of the Python interpreter at the same time, but part of the point of numpy is that it's implemented in C and not subject to contention for the GIL between different threads that numpy itself spawns as part of a single operation; so when you use numpy in a correct and appropriate way, you generally aren't bottlenecked by the GIL in the first place, so you pay multiprocessing's costs but get no gain).

@CharlesDuffy All of this is very true, and certainly, a first step is to know if you can twiddle with your numpy disrtibution (e.g. use Intel VML), although you can use numpy and multiprodessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory to use a numpy.ndarray that is using shared memory directly. Here is an interesting question/answer that gets into the various ways numpy can work (and talks about numba and numexpr as well)

Multiprocessing with a multiprocessing.Manager.List is not going to be faster, you are going to incur the IPC overhead from copying state. Now, you may be able to use multiprocessing.SharedMemory with numpy arrays efficiently, however, I would also suggest trying numexpr, which is supposed to help for this particular use case of having many operations that create needless intermediate arrays. Here is a simple test:
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne

import time


X = 0
Y = 1
N = 2000000

max_x = -100000
max_y = -100000
min_x = 100000
min_y = 100000

points = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, (N, 2))

max_x_index = np.argmax(points[:, X])
max_y_index = np.argmax(points[:, Y])
min_x_index = np.argmin(points[:, X])
min_y_index = np.argmin(points[:, Y])

p_right = points[max_x_index]
p_top = points[max_y_index]
p_left = points[min_x_index]
p_bottom = points[min_y_index]

start = time.perf_counter()

def pure_numpy():
    top_right = points[
        points[:, X] > ((points[:, Y] - p_top[Y]) / (p_right[Y] - p_top[Y])) * (p_right[X] - p_top[X]) + p_top[X]
    ]
    top_left = points[
        points[:, X] < ((points[:, Y] - p_top[Y]) / (p_left[Y] - p_top[Y])) * (p_left[X] - p_top[X]) + p_top[X]
    ]
    bottom_right = points[
        points[:, X] > ((points[:, Y] - p_bottom[Y]) / (p_right[Y] - p_bottom[Y])) * (p_right[X] - p_bottom[X]) + p_bottom[X]
    ]
    bottom_left = points[
        points[:, X] < ((points[:, Y] - p_bottom[Y]) / (p_left[Y] - p_bottom[Y])) * (p_left[X] - p_bottom[X]) + p_bottom[X]
    ]

for _ in range(100):
    pure_numpy()

print(time.perf_counter() - start)

start = time.perf_counter()

def using_numexpr():
    top_right = points[
        ne.evaluate(
            # points[:, X] > ((points[:, Y] - p_top[Y]) / (p_right[Y] - p_top[Y])) * (p_right[X] - p_top[X]) + p_top[X]
            "pointsX > ((pointsY - p_topY) / (p_rightY - p_topY)) * (p_rightX - p_topX) + p_topX",
            dict(pointsX=points[:, X], pointsY=points[:, Y], p_topY=p_top[Y], p_rightY=p_right[Y], p_rightX=p_right[X], p_topX=p_top[X])
        )
    ]
    top_left = points[
        # points[:, X] < ((points[:, Y] - p_top[Y]) / (p_left[Y] - p_top[Y])) * (p_left[X] - p_top[X]) + p_top[X]
        ne.evaluate(
            "pointsX < ((pointsY - p_topY) / (p_leftY - p_topY)) * (p_leftX - p_topX) + p_topX",
            dict(pointsX=points[:, X], pointsY=points[:, Y], p_topY=p_top[Y], p_leftY=p_left[Y], p_leftX=p_left[X], p_topX=p_top[X])
        )
    ]
    bottom_right = points[
        # points[:, X] > ((points[:, Y] - p_bottom[Y]) / (p_right[Y] - p_bottom[Y])) * (p_right[X] - p_bottom[X]) + p_bottom[X]
        ne.evaluate(
            "pointsX > ((pointsY - p_bottomY) / (p_rightY - p_bottomY)) * (p_rightX - p_bottomX) + p_bottomX",
            dict(pointsX=points[:, X], pointsY=points[:, Y], p_bottomY=p_bottom[Y], p_rightY=p_right[Y], p_rightX=p_right[X], p_bottomX=p_bottom[X])
        )
    ]
    bottom_left = points[
        #points[:, X] < ((points[:, Y] - p_bottom[Y]) / (p_left[Y] - p_bottom[Y])) * (p_left[X] - p_bottom[X]) + p_bottom[X]
        ne.evaluate(
            "pointsX < ((pointsY - p_bottomY) / (p_leftY - p_bottomY)) * (p_leftX - p_bottomX) + p_bottomX",
            dict(pointsX=points[:, X], pointsY=points[:, Y], p_bottomY=p_bottom[Y], p_leftY=p_left[Y], p_leftX=p_left[X], p_bottomX=p_bottom[X])
            
        )
    ]

for _ in range(100):
    using_numexpr()

print(time.perf_counter() - start)

I get results like:
(py312) Juans-MBP:foo juan$ python testing.py
10.898050098097883
7.235401042038575

So consistently faster.
I'm on my 10-year old laptop with only 4 logical cores, numexpr leverages multiple cores, it could work better on a better machine. You can also look into various ways to improve the performance like using Intel's Vector Math Library.
If you do want to use multiprocessing, you can use multiprocessing.shared_memory but it requires some care on to reconsruct a numpy array object from the shared memory (keeping track of dtypes and shape). See this answer to another question specifically about how to do that

It took only 0.03 seconds. Great! Thank you. Could you please recommend some good references for the method you used? This is just the first part of an algorithm in the field of computational geometry in computer science, and there are still many remaining parts that I need to implement using multiprocessing, so I need to learn

@MamaD I didn't use multiprocessing, I used numexpr numpy-specific library, I linked to the user guide for the numexpr library above, but here it is again. I just translated your code directly. Read more about the library in the link. It's basically designed for this exact use-case

The algorithm must recursively repeat a similar process for points at four regions top_right, top_left, bottom_right, bottom_left. Do you recommend me to use multiprocessing for such recursive process?

@MamaD this question is recommending you use numexpr, not multiprocessing.  Multi processing would be another approach altogether, which you definitely shouldn't combine with numpexpr, because numexpr already leverages all the cores. multiprocessing with a shared memory is a bit complex, but feasible. Although, you'd have to test out to see how it compares to this numexpr approach
